# Svelte import { x } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/x';

Tags: javascript, import, svelte, sveltekit

So I'm building an App with svelte, and I'm trying to import the `transformers.js` library

I tried the code `import { pipeline } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@xenova/transformers@2.3.0';`

Yet I receive the error `Cannot find module 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@xenova/transformers@2.3.0' imported from '/home/projects/story-ai-h9fvbs/src/routes/create/+page.svelte'`

The error itself makes sense, as the file wouldn't be there, and I know the CDN link works, so why is svelte looking for it there? How do I fix that?

also, I saw [This Example](https://svelte.dev/repl/7a7de2ad8f9648bd8ff10929156334c5?version=4.0.5) but it uses `await import('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/svelte-qrcode')` while I'm trying to get another format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These kinds of imports are apparently not supported during server-side rendering. You could open an issue about this in [the repository](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit).

My recommendation would be to just install the module locally and import from there.

[Turning off SSR](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/page-options#ssr) would also fix the error as the import would work on the client, though this comes with its own downsides.